# Nltk module not finding correct English words python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I downloaded both "words" and "wordnet" for the "NLTK" library for python:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import words
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
nltk.download('words')
nltk.download('wordnet')
```

to check if the words from a list are in English or not.

However when running the script it does not recognize any of the words as English.

Here is my script:

```
samplewords=['accident scene','a%32','j & quod','accident season','academic discount','academic diary','academic dictionary']

for word in samplewords:
    if word in words.words():
        print('English',word)
    else:
        print('Not English',word)

for word in samplewords:
    if not wordnet.synsets(word):
        print('Not english',word)
    else:
        print('English',word)
```

Here is what I get for both the above:

```
Not english accident scene
Not english a%32
Not english j & quod
Not english accident season
Not english academic discount
Not english academic diary
Not english academic dictionary
```

My expected result:

```
    English accident scene
    Not english a%32
    Not english j & quod
    English accident season
    English academic discount
    English academic diary
    English academic dictionary
```

How can I make sure that the library recognize that those are English words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `words()` contains the individual words of the corpus, not word collocations.

What you need is something like this to check whether each individual word is in `words.words()` (which will, however, classify non-existent collocations like 'dictionary season' as English words too):

```
for word in samplewords:
    if all([w in words.words() for w in word.split()]):
        print('English',word)
    else:
        print('Not English',word)
```

Result:

```
English accident scene
Not English a%32
Not English j & quod
English accident season
English academic discount
English academic diary
English academic dictionary
```